# Change size of Panorama item

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want that the height of one of my Panorama items is higher than usual just like in the TeamViewer app. The height should actually match with the Screen. That Panorama item should be entirely filled with a single canvas. How can I do that?

Comment: What does the TeamViewer app *do* with Panorama items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to increase the size of all the items like the TeamViewer app then just edit the TitleTemplate and change the font size of the title, here is an example of a header with a much shorter title area:

```
       <phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ''}" FontSize="30" Margin="14,34,0,0"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
```

If you want to make just one panorama item higher then you should just set a negative top margin on just this panorama item.